# What is the physical interpretation of four-force in SR?

Tags: special-relativity, forces, reference-frames, momentum, time

Four-force in SR is the ratio of the relativistic momentum to the proper time $\tau$, however, the three-force has a different definition so that the coordinate time of $t$ replaces the proper one. Inasmuch as $dt=\gamma d\tau$, it seems that the three-force indicates something completely different from that the four-force does. I want to know if these definitions are compatible with each other and which one is preferred to solving physical problems.

For instance, we know that if a force vector is measured to be $F'$ in the rest frame of reference, this force is measured to be Lorentz contracted by the observer who moves at a constant $v$ perpendicular to $F'$ according to the three-force definition for the transverse directions:
$$F=\alpha F'\space,$$ where $\alpha=\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$. I do want to know what the four-force predicts for these transverse components. Does, in this case, four-force agree with the three-force and predict the same $F=\alpha F'$? If not, which one is correct and physically measurable/applicable?

Answer (score 3):

The four-force is the only kind of force that makes physical sense.

You can always obtain the three-force from the four-force by discarding the $t$ component (projecting onto the $xyz$ hyperplane) and dividing the rest by $dt/dτ$. Neither of those operations is physically sensible, because $t$ is a coordinate on the same footing as $x,y,z$, and they shouldn't be treated differently, unless you're taking a Newtonian limit.

If the object on which the force acts is at rest in the primed system, and its (Lorentz-)invariant mass is constant, then the four-force is purely spatial in the primed system.

Supposing the four-force is $f = f_{x'} \hat{x'} + f_{y'} \hat{y'}$, and the relative velocity of the frames is in the $x$ (or equivalently $x'$) direction, then $\hat{x'} = γ(\hat x + v \hat t)$ and $\hat{y'} = \hat y$, so

$$f = γv f_{x'} \hat t + γ f_{x'} \hat x + f_{y'} \hat y$$

To get the three-force from this, you drop the $\hat t$ or $\hat{t'}$ component and divide the rest by $dt/dτ = γ$ or $dt'/dτ = 1$. This gives you

$$\begin{eqnarray}
F' &=& f_{x'} \hat{x'} + f_{y'} \hat{y'} \\
F &=& f_{x'} \hat x + (f_{y'}/γ) \hat y
\end{eqnarray}$$

which shows that the three-force in the unprimed frame is unchanged in the parallel direction and smaller by a factor of $γ=1/α$ in the perpendicular direction.

Comment: Thank you. However, your first equation shows that the transverse component remains unchanged according to the four-force, whereas the same component in your third equation reduces by $1/\gamma$. Which one is the *real* measurement of the said force component from the standpoint of the moving observer? These results are different and we cannot take both of them simultaneously for a specific measurement.

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry For any particular well-defined experiment, you can calculate what it will measure. You can devise experiments that measure the components of the four-force or the components of the three-force. None of those experiments is any more real than any other. It's usually easier to analyze experiments in terms of the four-force, whatever they're measuring.

Comment: Assume that we have a piston and cylinder. The piston exerts a force on a spring and contracts it. Is a moving observer, who does not know if the cylinder contains some compressed gas or a contracted spring or a uniform electric field with a charged piston, confused about applying the three- or four-force to judge the force from his viewpoint until someone makes him known of the containment of the cylinder?!

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry Well maybe there is more information in the direction of a 4-vector, compared to a 3-vector. As the length of the 4-vector seems to be telling us less info, compared to the length of a 3-vector.

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry I don't really understand your second comment. Your device probably measures proper acceleration. That's a Lorentz invariant property – not just the proper acceleration but the fact that the device measures it. A moving observer will see the device measure the proper acceleration. Anyone, whether moving or stationary, can analyze the device however they want, as long as they're mathematically consistent. There is no method an observer *must* use. That's as wrong as the idea that there's an absolute reference frame that determines true velocities.

Comment: @benrg Well, if it is really device-dependent, I can claim that I have invented a clock that, contrary to SR prediction, measures *time expansion* rather than time dilation for a moving frame. And then, I claim that there is no such thing as time dilation for some moving frames/objects/clocks. Is it rational?! But we know that in SR time dilation is something measurable using any clock regardless of its structure. The same is true for length contraction measured by *rulers*.  How can it be possible that this does not work for force or any other physical qualities?

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry Clocks measure proper time, i.e. worldline length, just like odometers measure distance traveled. Odometers don't measure distance times $\sqrt{1+m^2}$ where $m$ is the slope of the line you're traveling on relative to some arbitrary reference "horizontal". They just measure distance. Likewise, clocks don't measure time dilated by $\sqrt{1-v^2}$. They just measure time. "Time dilation" is a fairly complicated concept that requires setting up a coordinate system. "Three-force" is a related coordinate concept. You can use them to solve problems but it's not necessary to.